# Share info in Whatsapp via web link

Tags: javascript, html, web, hyperlink, whatsapp

I've been trying for a while build some method to share information from my web page via the Whatsapp application.

I actually found an easy method to do it using this code:

```
<a href="https://web.whatsapp.com/send?text=textToshare" target="_blank">Share via Whatsapp</a>
```

And it works great, but i still don't find how to know if the user really shared the information, or just got back to the web page.

Is there a way to make this work?

Thanks.

Comment: Here are some information: https://www.quora.com/Will-it-be-possible-to-integrate-WhatsApps-share-button-on-a-website-and-share-different-content-to-my-WhatsApp-contacts-using-WhatsApp-Web-from-a-desktop

Comment: @ssc-hrep3 thank you for your response. I just reviewed the information in the link you posted, and there is not information related with my issue. It is fine to know when somebody click on the share button, but i still don't find a way to validate if the information was shared or not. I.E.: With how many people did the information shared?...

Comment: Take a look at this topic and see if you can use it. [The php WhatsApp library](https://github.com/mgp25/Chat-API/wiki/WhatsAPI-Documentation)

Answer (score 1):

[It doesn't seem like you can.](http://mashable.com/2015/03/25/whatsapp-developers-api/#uTuGnnraYOqR) What's app doesn't seem to have an API much less analytics or webhooks.

The only way you could potentially do this would be to have it launch an iframe and inject javascript to track their interactions. This won't work because of cross domain security measures (think of the nasty things you could do if you weren't well intentioned). The iframe would need to be on the same domain as yours.